# dataTables ajax json data to become clickable rows

Tags: datatables

My dataTables table of 600 chess games was too slow. I was using php to write out the table data. I instead used ajax and it renders much faster now.

I want to make a row clickable based on "game" and hide the "game" field.

MY JSON STRUCTURE:

```js
{
"game": "5581",
"Date": "12/18/2010",
"Event": "RCC Saturday Open",
"ECO": "C00",
"White": "Nikolayev, Igor (FM)",
"WhiteElo": "2380",
"Black": "Spencer, Douglas",
"BlackElo": "1902",
"Result": "1-0"
},
```

MY JAVASCRIPT:

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#cccr').DataTable( {
"createdRow": function(row, data, index) {$(row).attr('game', data.game);},

"deferRender": true,
"oSearch": {"sSearch": "<?php echo ($_GET['player']); ?>"},
 "aaSorting": [],
 "bPaginate": false,
 "bLengthChange": true,
 "bFilter": true,
 "bSort": true,
 "bInfo": true,
 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
 "sScrollY": "25rem",
 "responsive": true,
 "bAutoWidth":true,
 "autoWidth": true,
 "ajax": "games.ajax",
 "columns": [

  { "data": "Date" },
  { "data": "Event" },
  { "data": "ECO" },
  { "data": "White" },
  { "data": "WhiteElo" },
  { "data": "Black" },
  { "data": "BlackElo" },
  { "data": "Result" },
  { "data": "game", visible : false }
 ]

 } );

$("#cccr").on('click', 'tr', function() {
   alert('basic.php?game='+$(this).attr('game')); 

} );

</script>
```

Some kind coder showed me how to make the "game" field clickable. But I want to hide the game field and make the entire row clickable as in:

```
basic.php?game=5579
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [**`createdRow`**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) callback :

```js
createdRow: function(row, data, index) {
   $(row).attr('game', data.game);
}
```

`row` holds the rendered `<tr>` element, `data` holds the JSON item. The above add the `game` value to the `<tr>` element as an attribute. After that, implement a click handler to the dataTable rows that takes care of the redirect :

```js
$("#cccr").on("click", "tr", function() {
   window.location.href = 'basic.php?game='+$(this).attr('game');
})
```

You can hide the game column simply by `{ "data": "game", visible : false }`

Comment: I added your code (see above) but it crashed the table. Any errors in my createdRow ? I think there might be, I am *not* crisp with such exacting js syntax.

Comment: @verlager, your `createdRow` looks fine, see this little demo where I have pasted your line in -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hj49b7qq/1/** - it looks OK, hopefully the `<script>` in your updated code is for demonstration only. `<script>`'s inside `<script>`'s will make the entire script to fail.

Comment: I copied your code into my web page and also into the above. It just doesn't seem to work.. -no data is displayed. Why is that?

Comment: @verlager, my guess is you have a comma too much, or less, lacking a closing curly or something like that. Impossible to tell without seeing the code. Can you take the fiddle above and paste all your script code into it and update? Just to see what you are dealing with, it is certainly not createdRow that causes it all to crash since it not have anything to do with population of data.

Comment: @verlager, great you got it to work! What was the problem? BTW, you can give the <tr>'s a mouseover "hand" (as links normally has) by adding the CSS ->`#cccr tbody tr { cursor : pointer; }`